# List of Error With DNS

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ip

I am working in linux system.

Is it possible to receive any error report when DNS does not exist, DNS does not respond, DNS failed to resolve a name?

If it is possible to detect different error ?

From Where I Can get list of error which can be obtained with DNS (Linux )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you use *named* in Linux you can enable logging by running

```
rndc querylog
```

after that you should check you system log file (/var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog) for messages. To disable logging run the command again.